# How do I traverse through a linked list after adding tails rather than heads

Tags: java, linked-list

This is for an assignment, but I'm not trying to copy and paste code, I want to know why this is happening. Part of the assignment is to output a polynomial expression, and I must do so by order of the highest degree. From my understanding, if I continuously add a head, the expression will be in reverse, so I've decided instead to add to the end of the list (the tail). I thought this way, I could print out every item while traversing the list. However, it would appear that for some reason, a reference might be lost in the list and I can only output the head instead of the rest of the list. If try to start at the tail, it will be in reverse. So unless there's some workaround to this, perhaps you guys can help me understand what I'm doing wrong, so I can get a better grasp about linked lists. By the way, I can only implement singly linked lists, not doubly, for the purposes of the assignment.

Here is my code... The main focus here are the toString, addToStart, and addToEnd methods method outside of the Term class which prints out my results. So for example, when I input 3 terms of the expressions, I only get the term in the head of the list, the other two are lost. Also, please note this code is incomplete.

```
public class Polynomial {

private Term head;
private Term tail;

public Polynomial () {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
}

public Polynomial (Polynomial poly) {
    copyOfPolynomial();

}

public Polynomial copyOfPolynomial() {

    Polynomial poly = null;
    return poly;

}

public void addToStart(double coef, int deg) {                  //Step 1: User inputs values at the start of the list
    head = new Term(coef, deg, head);
}

public void addToEnd(double coef, int deg) {                    //Step 2: Method is used if user wishes to add more terms
    tail = new Term(coef, deg, tail);
}

public int numberOfTerms() {                                    //Method is used to determine number of terms in polynomial

    int count = 0;
    Term position = head;
    count++;
    position = tail;
    while(position != null) {
        count++;
        position = position.link;
    }
    return count;
}

//public Polynomial add(Polynomial poly) {                      //The sum of the original polynomial with its derivative

//}

public double evaluate(double x) {                              //This method calculates the result when an input is entered for x

    return 0.0;
}

//public Polynomial derivative() {                              //This method does the derivative of poly1

//}

//public Polynomial integral() {                                //This method does the integration of the derivative (poly2)

//}

public void readPolynomial() {                                  //This method prompts the user input a value for x

}

public String toString() {                                      

    String strPoly = "";
    Term position = head;
    while(position != null) {
        strPoly += position.toString();
        position = position.link;
    }

    return "The polynomial you have just entered is " + strPoly;
}

public boolean equals(Polynomial poly) {

    return true;
}

/*
 * Class Term starts here
 */

private class Term {

    private double coefficient;
    private int degree;
    private Term link;

    public Term() {
        coefficient = 0.0;
        degree = 0;
        link = null;
    }

    public Term(double coef, int deg, Term linkValue) {
        coefficient = coef;
        degree = deg;
        link = linkValue;
    }

    public boolean setData(double coef, int deg) {

        coefficient = coef;
        degree = deg;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean setLink(Term newLink) {

        link = newLink;
        return true;
    }

    public double getCoefficient() {

        return coefficient;
    }

    public int getDegree() {

        return degree;
    }

    public Term getLink() {

        return link;
    }

    public String toString() {                                          //Step 3: Program outputs polynomial string depending on how inputs are applied

        String strCoef = String.valueOf(coefficient);
        String strDeg = String.valueOf(degree);
        if(degree == 0) 
            return strCoef;
        else
            return strCoef + "x^" + strDeg;
    }

    public boolean equals() {

        return true;
    }


}
}
```

Comment: This looks like the Comp249 assignment lol

Comment: Elements added to the head and the tail of your list never get connected. Also adding to the tail has to add the element after the current tail (then replace the old tail with the new one), not add the current tail after the new one.

Comment: When you insert at the start, you must first create a new Term and point it to the current head. Once you do that, you can say head = theNewTerm.  But you must still check certain cases like when the head is null

Comment: @ fabian, I had a feeling it was something like that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have for my addToStart() method, just to give you an idea.

```
/**
 * Validates a term before it is added to a Polynomial.
 * @param coef must not be 0
 * @param deg must be nonnegative
 * @param term term to return
 * @return term if valid coefficient and degree, null otherwise
 */
private Term validatedTerm(double coef, int deg, Term term) {
    Term temp = new Term();
    if(!temp.setData(coef, deg) || !temp.setLink(term))
        return null;
    return temp;
}

/**
 * Adds a term to the start of the Polynomial. Uses Term validatedTerm(double, int, Term)<br />
 * Will not add term if not validated.
 * @param coef coefficient of term
 * @param deg degree of term
 */
public void addToStart(double coef, int deg) {
    Term term;
    if((term = validatedTerm(coef, deg, null)) == null)
        return;

    if(head != null)
        term.setLink(head);     
    else
        tail = term;

    head = term;
    numTerms++;
}
```

Comment: Haha, yes, you're correct, it's the 249 assignment. So from I gather, do you use a while loop for the addToStart method to plug in the terms? I guess I didn't have a complete understanding of the assignment then.

Comment: Well, the point of addToStart  (and addToEnd) is just to add a term to a Polynomial. This would be done from the Driver program when you prompt the user for the terms. They'll enter a coefficient and a degree, and youll just take those values and addToEnd(coef, degree) just that one term, then you ask them again, so yeah that part is in a loop.   But in the addToStart method itself, you are always just adding one term to the Polynomial each method call

Comment: Right, I just wanted to make sure, I was using those methods exactly the way you put it. My main problem is just outputting these terms in order. There's probably not enough time to change everything but it I will still try it to get a better understand before the exam.

Comment: I dont think you have to output them in order, just in whatever order they were entered. That's what I interpreted. If you look towards the bottom of the assignment sheet at the 'sample output screen', you'll notice the first sentence says "Enter a polynomial - Start with term with highest degree. Enter coefficient then degree:"   Which to me means we dont have to make sure we output them starting at the highest degree. That's my interpretation so I didn't waste time on it, if you interpret it the same way then definitely don't waste time on it!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't bother fixing it that way anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You ought to try to diagram what is happening with boxes and arrows. It looks like the problem is when you add to the tail of the list. You need to update the old tail so that it points to the new tail instead of into oblivion.